# AudioSource not playing before GameObject is destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

In this procedure, when the fire button is clicked, it creates a laser object that then flies across the screen, when it hits the bad guy object, it plays an explosion sound and deletes the laser and the bad guy object.

I can't get it to play an explosion sound, but it does delete the two objects and doesn't toss any type of error.  I attached the explosion sound to the bad guy, and said play the bad guy's `AudioSource` before the objects are destroyed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LaserFire : MonoBehaviour {

    public float laserSpeed = 10f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //when the shot is fired, play the sound effect for a shot fired
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //moves the object across the screen over time
        transform.Translate(0f, laserSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitObject)
    {
        //if the laser hits a bad guy, play the audio clip attached to the bad guy
        hitObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        Destroy(hitObject.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever get your problem resolved? If not, please update your question to indicate how existing answers have not successfully answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that although the `AudioSource` is successfully playing (since there are no errors), it's being destroyed before it can actually get very far in its sound clip. Right after you start to play it, you `Destroy()` its associated `GameObject`, which effectively stops the playback right away.

To address this, consider using [`AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitObject)
{
    //if the laser hits a bad guy, play the audio clip attached to the bad guy
    AudioSource hitAudio = hitObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(hitAudio.clip, transform.position);
    Destroy(hitObject.gameObject);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

This method will instantiate a temporary object with the `AudioSource` on it, play it, and destroy it once playback finishes. Because of this, you should keep an eye on your usage of this method should your scale increase; it could potentially create performance issues due to the garbage generated, so [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling) might be more applicable then.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response!  This isn't working for some reason. However, when I comment out Destroy(hitObject.gameObject); you're right that it does play the sound then; however even with creating the temporary object, it's still not playing.  Should the sound clip not be stored on the object being destroyed?

Comment: @uofarob Ah, you're right! Sorry, I was thinking of `PlayClipAtPoint()` - I've updated my answer accordingly, let me know if that helps.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you much!